# UI Automation in UWP application for detecting controls in another application

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to access control elements of an application using UI Automation framework. The current codebase is built is a UWP application and I want to extend this feature on it. I wrote a c++ script using UIAutomation to extract control elements. However, the same code run in UWP app gives different result that that of a console c++ application. There is something stopping the UWP application from accessing ui elements. Is there some way in which UI Automation framework can be used in UWP?

The following is a part of the code that abstracts the number of elements inside a foreground running application. This code gives very few control elements ( less than 5) when run from a UWP. The same script gives around 30 - 600 elements when run from console application.

```
    HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
    IUIAutomationElement* temp;
    uia->aut->ElementFromHandle(foreground, &temp);
    wcout << uia->name(temp) << endl;
    IUIAutomationTreeWalker* walker;
    uia->aut->get_RawViewWalker(&walker);

    IUIAutomationElementArray* arr;
    IUIAutomationCondition* condition;
    uia->aut->CreateTrueCondition(&condition);
    temp->FindAll(TreeScope_Subtree, condition, &arr);
    int sz; arr->get_Length(&sz);
    cout << sz << endl;
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: @IInspectable Alright , made the edits

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I hope the attached code would be helpful.

Comment: Do any of the calls actually fail? Would be helpful to see the error handling. Regardless, this could be a limitation of the UWP. There's a `uiAutomation` capability listed under [restricted capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capabilities). I don't know how true that information still is.

Comment: @IInspectable , the calls do not fail at all. The number of elements that they extract is significantly different though. 
I have tried adding uiAutomation capability as well.